# Use two columns of a Pandas DataFrame and add a new column. Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe which looks like this

```
Currency    Amount    Country
EUR         12.06     France
USD         10.23     USA
INR         122.17    India
INR         422.01    India
USD         8.06      USA
```

I have a function which would take currency name i.e. **Currency** column and use **Amount** to convert to a common currency

```
def convert_an_amount(amount,curr,target_currency):
    if curr in c.currencies:
        return c.convert(amount, curr , target_currency)
    return np.nan
```

What I want to do is create the column of our dataframe

```
def convert_to_common(amount,curr_name,target_curr):
    currency_coverted_variable - 
    ... required code ...
```

I would like to have the following dataframe

```
Currency    Amount    Country   Common Currency(EUR)
EUR         12.06     France    x
USD         10.23     USA       x
INR         122.17    India     x
INR         422.01    India     x
USD         8.06      USA       x
```

Is there any way to code this function?
I am using a library which would convert the value in the function but how to facilitate the creation of the dataframe?

The condition for c.convert is that it only converts one value at a time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`DataFrame.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) with your function:

```
df['new'] = df.apply(lambda x: convert_to_common(x['Amount'], x['Currency'], 'EUR'), axis=1)
```

I think you can create dictionary for `rate`, then use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) and multiple by `Amount` if need better performance:

```
eur = {'EUR':1, 'USD':2, 'INR':3}

df['new'] = df['Currency'].map(eur) * df['Amount']
print (df)
  Currency  Amount Country      new
0      EUR   12.06  France    12.06
1      USD   10.23     USA    20.46
2      INR  122.17   India   366.51
3      INR  422.01   India  1266.03
4      USD    8.06     USA    16.12
```

**Detail**:

```
print (df['Currency'].map(d))
0    1
1    2
2    3
3    3
4    2
Name: Currency, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

Here
https://chrisalbon.com/python/data_wrangling/pandas_make_new_columns_using_functions/

you can see an example where you create your function (in your case convert_to_common)

```
# Create a function that takes two inputs, pre and post
def pre_post_difference(pre, post):
    # returns the difference between post and pre
    return post - pre
```

and then you can call it adding a variable in your dataframe

```
# Create a variable that is the output of the function
df['score_change'] = pre_post_difference(df['preTestScore'], df['postTestScore'])

# View the dataframe
df
```

Comment: The problem is that c.convert in the function convert_an_amoutn would only convert a sinlge value it doesn't take a column